# Преобразование char[] в string

Tags: c++

Есть массив `char[]`. Нужно преобразовать его в `string`.
Как это можно сделать наиболее просто?

Comment: Наиболее просто, это ознакомиться со списком конструкторов std::string. Или Вы не читаете документацию на то, чем пользуетесь?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Почитайте эту статью: "[**Строки как нуль-терминированные массивы char.**](http://studopedia.ru/3_20306_stroki-kak-nul-terminirovannie-massivi-char.html)".

Вот краткая выдержка:

> Один из способов организовать работу со строками - это использование
>   одномерных массивов типа `char`. Тогда строка символов – это одномерный
>   массив типа `char`, заканчивающийся нулевым байтом.
>
> Нулевой байт – это байт, каждый бит которого равен нулю, при этом для
>   нулевого байта определена символьная константа `\0` (признак окончания
>   строки, или нуль-терминатор). По нулевому байту функции, работающие со
>   строками, определяют место окончания строки. Если они читают строку,
>   то воспринимают ее только до первого нуль-терминатора; если они
>   создают строку, то записывают нуль-терминатор в ее конец.

Еще полезно будет почитать ответ на этот вопрос: [**How to convert a char array to a string?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8960101/2486051)

Вот решение:

```
char arr[ ] = "Простая проверка";
string str = string(arr);
cout << str;
// "Простая проверка"
```

Вот пример на [**Ideone**](http://ideone.com/3C9vEz)

Answer (score 7):

Если массив содержит си строку, заканчивающуюся `'\0'`, то просто присваиванием

```
char s[] = "test";
std::string str = s;
// или явно как параметр конструктора
std::string str2(s);
```

Если не завершается `'\0'`, то надо явно указать размер

```
char s[] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't'};
std::string str(s, sizeof(s));
```

Answer (score -2):

Ну простым присваиванием же...

Comment: Приведи пример, я думаю это хороший вопрос, сам неоднократно сталкивался

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/84153)

Comment: @VAndrJ, ну и почему же не является?