# работа конструктора String(const char*)

Tags: c++

Был такой вопрос:
[Преобразование char[] в string](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/528680/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-char-%D0%B2-string)

В дополнение к нему у меня возник дополнительный вопрос по работе конструктора String(char *).
Что происходит при вызове такого конструктора - выделяется отдельная область памяти для класса String в которую копируется содержимое char * ?

Либо формируется какая то ссылка на имеющийся char * и переменную char * уже нельзя уничтожать?

Т.е. в переменную класса String попадает копия строки char * - или попадает некий указатель на некую область памяти, которую нужно будет сохранять ?

```
const char txt[]="Пример";

char * b = &txt;
String s(b);
```

Comment: А что за класс String?  это Вы так назвали `std::string`?

Comment: прошу прощения - просто пишу для Arduino, там std::string почему то назвали String

Comment: [Там](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) совершенно другой класс. Хоть и имя похожее.

Comment: Дополнил ответ про Arduino

Comment: `char * b = &txt;` - это уже некорректно.

Answer (score 3):

В [описании конструктора](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) `std::string` сказано:

> from c-string (4) string (const char* s);
>
> Copies the null-terminated character sequence (C-string) pointed by s

т.е. копируется содержимое.

**UPD** в связи с комментариями про Arduino

Как верно заметил KoVadim, `String` и `std::string` - это совершенно разные классы.

На GitHub'е есть исходники в открытом доступе. Конкретно класс `String` описан в файле [WString.cpp](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/WString.cpp)

Там также как и в `std::string` конструктор копирует данные.

Comment: Вы внимательно читали мой комментарий?

Comment: @KoVadim, ваш комментарий содержит полезную информацию?

Comment: По вопросу совершенно не понятно, какой именно класс String имеет в виду. Поэтому ответить невозможно. Но я предположил, что там std::string. Поэтому да, мой комментарий содержит много полезной информации

Comment: Герман, спасибо что ткнули носом :)
Я предполагал - что скорее всего в конструкторе идет копирование - но вот найти подтверждение не смог, спасибо еще раз :)

Comment: Ага, собственно я был прав, А Герман поспешил