# Как правильно перевести char* в std::string? Почему получается строка из одного символа?

Tags: c++, строки, std

Передаю в функцию указатель на char[32]. Там записано, например 'AFL',указатель же указывает только на 'A'. Соответственно при:
`name_ = *name;`
Получаю name_ == "A". Как получить всю строку?

```
void PlanFor4D::createPlanFromKST(P4_POLETA_NBT * p4_poleta_nbt, char * name)    
{
  //do something

  name_ = *name; //name указывает на 'AFL', но в name_ записывается "A", а нужно "AFL"
}
```

Comment: Покажите фрагмент кода, из описания не очень понятно, что ві делаете.

Comment: @Harry, добавил код

Comment: @insolor , Я видел эту тему, она похожа, но не совсем та, поскольку меня интересовал не просто char[], а указатель на char[].

Comment: @insolor , поправил.

Comment: В коде у вас нигде нет `char*[]`, есть просто `char*`. Ну хотя голос за дубликат уберу, потому что там нет объяснения для конкретно вашей проблемы.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Преобразование char\[\] в string](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/528680/1365)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у name тип char*,  а у `*name` тип char. И соответственно вызываются разные функции класса std::string.

для `name`

```
std::string::operator=(char const*)
```

для `*name`

```
std::string::operator=(char)
```

Поэтому, просто пишите правильно

```
name_ = name; // звездочки нет!
```

(я вначале было подумал, что в name хранится в utf-16, но это было бы слишком уже:) но можно было бы получить похожий эффект)

Comment: спасибо большое,  очень помогло) Буду знать! Всего доброго! :)